# Убрать дублирование в массиве

Tags: php, opencart

Есть массив:

```
Array(
    [9] => 11879,16806,23736
    [37] => 11879,16806
)
```

Где 9,37 - это id бренда,
11879,16806...16806 - это id товара

Делаю так:

```
$data['manufacturers'] = array();

foreach ($products as $manufacturer_id => $product) {
    $manufacturer_info = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($manufacturer_id);

    if ($product) {
        $products_id = explode(",", $product);

        foreach ($products_id as $product_id) {
            $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

            if ($product_info) {
                $product_filters[] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                    'name' => $product_info['name']
                );
            }
        }
    } else {
        $product_filters = false;
    }

    if ($manufacturer_info) {
        $data['manufacturers'][] = array(
            'manufacturer_id' => $manufacturer_info['manufacturer_id'],
            'name' => $manufacturer_info['name'],
            'products_id' => $product,
            'products' => $product_filters
        );
    }
}
```

Получаю:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [manufacturer_id] => 9
        [name] => brend1
        [products_id] => 11879,16806,23736
        [products] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [product_id] => 11879
                [name] =>  Название товара 1
            )
            [1] => Array(
                [product_id] => 16806
                [name] => Название товара 2
            )
            [2] => Array(
                [product_id] => 23736
                [name] => Название товара 3
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [manufacturer_id] => 37
        [name] => brend2
        [products_id] => 11879,16806
        [products] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [product_id] => 11879
                [name] =>  Название товара 1
            )
            [1] => Array(
                [product_id] => 16806
                [name] => Название товара 2
            )
            [2] => Array(
                [product_id] => 23736
                [name] => Название товара 3
            )
            [3] => Array(
                [product_id] => 11879
                [name] =>  Название товара 4
            )
            [4] => Array(
                [product_id] => 16806
                [name] => Название товара 5
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Получается что во 2-м массиве товары с первого массива. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так что-бы товары не дублировались?
Т.е. что-бы получилось так:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [manufacturer_id] => 9
        [name] => brend1
        [products_id] => 11879,16806,23736
        [products] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [product_id] => 11879
                [name] =>  Название товара 1
            )
            [1] => Array(
                [product_id] => 16806
                [name] => Название товара 2
            )
            [2] => Array(
                [product_id] => 23736
                [name] => Название товара 3
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [manufacturer_id] => 37
        [name] => brend2
        [products_id] => 11879,16806
        [products] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [product_id] => 11879
                [name] =>  Название товара 1
            )
            [1] => Array(
                [product_id] => 16806
                [name] => Название товара 2
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен замысел. Вы пытаетесь получить данные по  всем товарам по брендам или только определённые во входном массиве? Опять же, если только определённые, то не ясно как вы определяете, что удалять дубли надо именно у следующего производителя а не у предыдущего?

Comment: Насколько я понял, вам просто надо очистить массив `$product_filters` в начале каждой итерации цикла:
`$product_filters = [];`

Comment: Нужно что-бы выводились только те id которые в [products_id]: https://pastenow.ru/6DIW0

Comment: @g4343 так занесите генерацию `manufacturers` внутрь цикла с выборкой товара, сразу выбрали, сразу занесли, никаких лишних массивов

Comment: @NTP Блин! Вы правы) Спасибо!